# How can I get ack to ignore *.orig files?

Tags: ack

I put this in my .ackrc:

```
--type-set=DUMB=*.orig
--noDUMB
```

... but I'm still seeing files like main.py.orig in my ack results. I tried doing `--type-set=DUMB=*.*.orig` too, but that didn't work either.

**More info**

Run from my command line (OSX Snow Leopard with :

```
timmfin at lorien in ~/dev/performable/rafa on landing-pages-csv-and-more!
± ack modules --python | grep '.orig'
src/rafa/main.py.orig:25:import rafa.ui.modules.helpers
src/rafa/main.py.orig:26:from rafa.ui.modules.performable_form import PerformableForm
src/rafa/main.py.orig:27:from rafa.ui.modules.page_form import PageEditForm
src/rafa/main.py.orig:28:from rafa.ui.modules.settings_form import SettingsForm
....

timmfin at lorien in ~/dev/performable/rafa on landing-pages-csv-and-more!
± cat ~/.ackrc 
--color
--sort-files
--smart-case

--type-set=sass=.sass
--type-set=coffee=.coffee

--ignore-dir=rafa/static
--ignore-dir=compiled
--ignore-dir=compressed

--ignore-dir=venv
--ignore-dir=build

timmfin at lorien in ~/dev/performable/rafa on landing-pages-csv-and-more!
± ack --version
ack 1.94
Running under Perl 5.10.0 at /usr/bin/perl
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*For ack version 1.x*

I found this worked if I removed the asterisk (from the [Ackmate wiki](https://github.com/protocool/AckMate/wiki))

```
--type-set=DUMB=.orig
--noDUMB
```

You can see what types of file ackmate supports by running (including those you've specified in ~/.ackrc):

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/PlugIns/AckMate.tmplugin/Contents/Resources/ackmate_ack --help type
```

Answer (score 89):

Now that ack 2.0 is available:

```
--ignore-file=ext:orig
```

, either on command line or `.ackrc`.

It is possible to ignore files by name. To ignore ctags generated files:

```
--ignore-file=is:tags
```

Filters for different uses can be found on [documentation](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.12-man.html#defining_your_own_types).

Comment: I wish this would be updated to the "accepted answer", this is the best way to do it now!

Comment: You can use `match` along with a regex to match filenames and `ext` for extensions. Exclude js files `--ignore-file=ext:js`. Exclude files with name foo and bar `--ignore-file='match:/foo|bar/'`. Escape the parameter with quotes in case of regex with `|` so that shell doesn't execute it as a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

For ack version 1.x use the following. In my case, I want to ignore .css files. I have to set the type called SOMETHING. Then set it to --noSOMETHING to remove it from search.

```
 ack --type-set=SOMETHING=.css --noSOMETHING "My Bitcoin."
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ack doesn't recognize .orig files in the first place.  I'm guessing you are somehow invoking `ack -a` either from your `ackrc` or `ACK_OPTIONS`.

Comment: I mainly use Ack via the AckMate plugin for Textmate (and I'm not sure what options it uses other than my .ackrc), but I also see the problem from ack on the command line. Updated my question for more detail

Comment: Try it with --noenv and see if your .orig get ignored.  Also, could your ack be aliased to ack -a?  Also, use ack -f to get a list of all the files that ack is interested in.

Comment: i got **ack: Invalid option in ~/.ackrc**

Comment: When did you get that error message?  What did you do in your ~/.ackrc?