# ack type doesnt work when dot is part of extension

Tags: ack

Trying to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6035819/340947) to eliminate garbage files from being `ack`'d, however my definition does not work:

```
--type-set=map=.min.map
--no-map
```

This still produces the result

```
$ ack MARK -l                       
public/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.map
```

Quite frustrating.

My workaround is `--ignore-file=is:jquery-2.1.1.min.map`

However I would like to banish all `*.min.map` files.

I really do not understand why ack had to invent a new flaky configuration syntax. What is wrong with supporting globs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is wrong with supporting globs.

ack doesn't support globbing in filetype detection because globbing is different between *nix and Windows.  Glob-based rules that used Unix-style globbing syntax would be confusing to Windows-based users.  Perl regexes are the same across all platforms, and much more flexible than globbing.

To solve your problem of matching `.min.map` files, if your single extension doesn't work, you can use a regex like so:

```
--ignore-file=match:[.]min[.]map$
```

ack uses many rules like that in its default ruleset.  You can use `ack --dump` to get a dump of ack's rules, and that can be handy to see how other filetypes are handled.

```
$ ack --dump | ack =match:
  --ignore-file=match:/[.-]min[.]js$/
  --ignore-file=match:/[.]css[.]map$/
  --ignore-file=match:/[.]css[.]min$/
  --ignore-file=match:/[.]js[.]map$/
  --ignore-file=match:/[.]js[.]min$/
  --ignore-file=match:/[.]min[.]css$/
  --ignore-file=match:/[._].*\.swp$/
  --ignore-file=match:/^#.+#$/
  --ignore-file=match:/core\.\d+$/
  --ignore-file=match:/~$/
```

Comment: However I have one follow-up question: How can I set the type of all `[.]min[.]map$` files to `map`? This: `--type-set=map=[.]min[.]map$` doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: It should be `--type-set=map:match:[.]min[.]map$`.  Look in the man page (or `ack --man`) for "Defining your own types".

Comment: OK i see. Not sure why my existing map `--type-set=jsx=.jsx` even works at all then.

Comment: Because when we went to ack 2.0, we made the old-style backward compatible with the ack 1.x syntax.

Comment: Hey @AndyLester I have a question for you -- I tried configuring ack with `--ignore-dir=/absolute/path/to/dir` and it doesn't work, in fact I was even more surprised upon reading the manpage which says that nested dirs are "NOT supported"... but it works for me, but only with relative paths...

Comment: I believe this is already reported at https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/291